# Expanding / collapsing selft-sizing table view cell with two labels

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to make table view with expanding / collapsing self-sizing cells with two labels. I want to show only the title label when the cell is collapsed. And show the title and details label when the cell is expanded. I want to make self-sized cell no matter if it is collapsed or expanded.

Now I have self-sizing cell only when it is expanded. But when I collapse cell, I don't know how to set proper height of the title.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    if cell.isDetailsHidden {
        expandedCells.append(indexPath)
    } else {
        if let index = expandedCells.indexOf(indexPath) {
            expandedCells.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()

    cell.isDetailsHidden = !cell.isDetailsHidden

    return indexPath
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if expandedCells.contains(indexPath) {
        return tableView.rowHeight
    } else {
        return 30.0  // how to find proper height?
    }
}
```

### Update

Now, I dynamically choose proper cell type in `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath)` and `tableView(_:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if expandedCells.contains(indexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTableViewCell

        cell.cellTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellDetails.text = details[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTitle", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTitleTableViewCell

        cell.cellTItle.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    if (tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CellTableViewCell) != nil {
        print("with details")
        if let index = expandedCells.indexOf(indexPath) {
            expandedCells.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    } else if (tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CellTitleTableViewCell) != nil {
        print("only title")
        expandedCells.append(indexPath)
    }

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    return indexPath
}
```

If I have only `UILabel`s in storyboard then reloading goes smoothly. But if I add `UIImage` to details cell then reloading cause a little jump, but it appears only when user is on the bottom of table view.

Do switching between prototype cells is a good and efficient solution? If not, what should I do instead?

Thanks in advance for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about image jumping issue. But recently in one of my projects used a collapse expend feature. And all the detail information was in individual cell which make it load smoothly i guess.

I'm sharing my segment of code for you:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

 return 1
 }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(myObject.count == 0 || myObject == nil)
    {
        let emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
        emptyLabel.text = "No Data Found"
        emptyLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        emptyLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.tableView?.backgroundView = emptyLabel

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        self.tableView?.backgroundView = nil
        return myObject.count+3
    }


 }


 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderSubHeaderTableViewCell



        cell.totalOrder.format = "%d";
        cell.totalOrder.countFrom(0,to: CGFloat(self.myObject.count),withDuration: 1.0)
        cell.totalAmount.format = "%.02f"
        cell.totalAmount.countFrom(0,to: CGFloat(NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self.totalAmount)!),withDuration: 1.0)

        cell.more.hidden = detail


        return cell


    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubHeaderCash", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderSubHeaderSecondTableViewCell


        cell.collection.format = "%d";
        cell.collection.countFrom(0,to: CGFloat(self.collection),withDuration: 1.0)
        cell.cash.format = "%.02f"
        cell.cash.countFrom(0,to: CGFloat(NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(cashAmount)!),withDuration: 1.0)



        return cell


    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubHeaderType", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderSubHeaderThirdTableViewCell

        cell.delivery.format = "%d";
        cell.delivery.countFrom(0,to: CGFloat(self.delivery),withDuration: 1.0)
        cell.paypal.format = "%.02f"
        cell.paypal.countFrom(0,to: CGFloat(NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(paypalAmount)!),withDuration: 1.0)


        return cell

    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderTableViewCell
        cell.setValue(myObject.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row-3) as! Order)


        return cell
    }



 }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2
    {
        detail = !detail

        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

        if tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) != nil {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! OrderSubHeaderTableViewCell
            cell.more.hidden = detail
        }



        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

    }
    else
    {
        self.delegate?.orderSelected(self.myObject[indexPath.row-3] as! Order,index: indexPath.row)

        if let detailViewController = self.delegate as? OrderDetailsTableViewController {

            detailViewController.delegate = self
            splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(detailViewController.navigationController!, sender: nil)
        }
    }




}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        return (!detail) ? 100 : 80
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {

        return (!detail) ? 0 : 80
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2 {

        return (!detail) ? 0 : 100
    }
    else{

        return 130
    }

}
```

here in collapsed mood only the "SubHeader" cell is visible and after expending the "SubHeadrCash" & "SubHeaderType" got visible . I controlled the switching with changing Cell heights and using a boolean var "detail"

**Updated**

For your scenario you can calculate the dynamic height of a label by using its string and calling boundingRectWithSize.

```
let labelWidth = label.frame.width
let maxLabelSize = CGSize(width: labelWidth, height: CGFloat.max)
let actualLabelSize = label.text!.boundingRectWithSize(maxLabelSize,      options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:    label.font], context: nil)
let labelHeight = actualLabelSize.height
```

Comment: I did similar thing previously, but I had a problem with setting the height of the row in `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath)`. In my case the title may be multiline, so I don't have a static height of it.